# Get last corner point of an isosceles triangle when given 2 points and asa of those points

Tags: java, geometry

I start off with only two points and an angle that belongs to both points. The only part I have left is the last Point and I don't want to brute force my way through this. So far I have all of the info listed below.

- Point A: given
- Point B: given
- Point C: (?, ?)
- Angle A: given (at Point A), same as Angle B
- Angle B: given (at Point B), same as Angle A
- Angle C: 180 - Angle*2~ (at Point C)
- Side AB: distance(Point~A & Point~B)
- Side AC: (Side~AB * Math.sin(Angle~A)) / Math.sin(Angle~C)
- Side BC: (Side~AB * Math.sin(Angle~B)) / Math.sin(Angle~C)

The Code I have so far is pretty much just this:
(tip: p is a Point, a is an Angle, d is a Side; 1 is A, 2 is B, 3 is C. I know my code is hard to read but it's my first draft.)

```
public static Point solve(Point p1, Point p2, double angle)
{
  //known
  double a1 = angle;
  double a2 = angle;
  double d12 = p1.distance(p2);
  //mathed
  double a3 = 180 - (angle*2);
  double d13 = (d12*Math.sin(a1))/Math.sin(a3);
  double d23 = (d12*Math.sin(a2))/Math.sin(a3);
  //mathed, mathed.
  Point p3 = null;
  return p3;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's P is center of AB segment, **P** = (**A** + **B**) / 2

Then PC vector is perpendicular to AP, and the length of PC is |**PC**| = |**AP**| / Tg(angle),    Tg = Tan = tangent

Let's Tg(angle) = t

First condition (dot product of perp vectors): PCx*APx+PCy*APy=0

Second one (squared lengths): t^2*(PCx*PCx+PCy*PCy) = APx*APx+APy*APy

Solution of this system (2 solutions, C point might be at the different sides of AB line):

PCx = +- APy/t

PCy = -+ APx/t

Be care: signs should be opposite!

And finally:

Cx = Px + PCx = Ax/2 + Bx/2 +- Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ay + By)

Cy = Py + PCy = Ay/2 + By/2 -+ Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ax + Bx)

first point:

Cx1 = Ax/2 + Bx/2 + Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ay + By);

Cy1 = Ay/2 + By/2 - Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ax + Bx);

second point:

Cx2 = Ax/2 + Bx/2 - Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ay + By);

Cy2 = Ay/2 + By/2 + Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ax + Bx)

Comment: is Tg tangent and Ctg co-Tangent? P is the mid-point of A & B, right? could you explain AP{y,x} abit, I don't see the way you got to it... I just noticed the second '=' in the final bit, is this correct? Cx1 = Ax/2 + Bx/2 + Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ay + By);
Cy1 = Ay/2 + By/2 - Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ax + Bx);
Cx2 = Ax/2 + Bx/2 - Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ay + By);
Cy2 = Ay/2 + By/2 + Ctg(angle)/2 * (Ax + Bx);

Comment: tangent, co-Tangent - yes. P is midpoint. AP is vector from A to P, and APx is x-component of this vector (AP.X if AP is point-type variable). About pair of final solutions - yes, you are right, this is correct

Comment: I made my own algorithm, could you please check my answer please?

Answer (score 1):

If you draw a line perpendicular to AB through the center of AB, it will intersect point C. Call the point where the line intersects the segment AB D. Translate this line to the x-axis, D to the origin, and AD to the y-axis

```
^ y
|
| A
o
|\
| \
|  \
|   \ C
o----o-----> x
D
```

Once you calculate the length DC, projecting C back into the original coordinate space should be a snap.

1. Angle C = 90 - Angle A
2. AC * cos Angle C = DC
3. DC = AC * cos (90 - Angle A)

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong but, midpoint is ((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2), perpendicular slope is -(x2-x1)/(y2-y1). I know there is a line with slope-point but this is where I got lost was at the translate step.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works. On an example of P1 = (-10,0), P2 = (10, 0), Angle = 45 degrees; I got (0, +-10) has the final answer, is this correct?

```
Mid Point = ( (x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2)
Slope Angle = arcTan(m) = arcTan((y2-y1) / (x2-x1))
Perpendicular Angle = Slope Angle +- 90
Distance = (distance(P1 & Mid Point)/sin(90-Angle)) * sin(Angle)

P3 = (cos(Perpendicular Angle)*Distance + Mid Point.x , sin(Perpendicular Angle)*Distance + mid Point.y)
```

The way I got this was a unit circle with an R of Distance, then go to the perpendicular angles and use cos for x and sin for y.
I got the distance by the law of sines on half the triangle (P1, Mid Point, P3) where MidPoint is the 90 degree.

Please give your advice on this, Thanks ~vzybilly~

Comment: You have to multiply Distance by factor 1/2 (because you use half of triangle with these angles)

Comment: I made a typo, the distance formula is actually: Distance = (distance(P1 & Mid Point)/sin(90-Angle)) * sin(Angle); is this correct?

Comment: Oh, I can see how that works, I was just going through the formula for the angle on that corner and kinda forgot about that...